# Overload operator >> for all enum types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have enumeration type , for which I overload the `operator>>`.

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &is,MyEnum& enumVar)
{
  int intVal;
  is>>intVal;
  enumVar = intVal;
  return is;
}
```

How to avoid writing this code for all future enum types, i.e how to write the function so it is applicable to all enum types?

Comment: You could use `templates` to achieve a genericity for your method, but you will need to use a constraining-mechanism to ensure that only your enums are accepted as arguments. Unfortunately, `constraints` are not supported by C++ that easily.

Comment: I know that I can do something with templates and boost::enable_if but I can't really understand how it actually works

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html

Comment: Tough one... I don't know about `boost`, sorry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the operator a template and enable it only if the template parameter is an enum (using `enable_if`):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::istream&>::type
operator >>(std::istream &is, T& enumVar)
{
  std::cout << "enum\n"; // just to see it is this one that gets used
  int intVal;
  is >> intVal;
  enumVar = static_cast<T>(intVal); // note the explicit cast to make it legal
  return is;
}
```

If you don't have C++11 avaliable, you can use boost's `type_traits` library.

Seeing your comment that you don't know exactly how `enable_if` works, here is a [link with a detailed explanation.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/enable-if)

In short, `enable_if` templates come in pairs - one with a member typedef of second template parameter to `type` when the condition (first template parameter) is true, and one without that typedef when condition is false. Template instantiations with false condition are invalid, because the member typedef does not exist. Such instantiation is then (instead of being a hard compiler error) discarded from overload set for later overload resolution. Read also about [SFINAE](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/SFINAE).

EDIT: boost's `enable_if` works slightly differently than the standard one. Use either:

```
boost::enable_if < boost::is_enum<T>, std::istream& >::type
                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                // expects a type
```

or

```
boost::enable_if_c < boost::is_enum<T>::value, std::istream& >::type
                  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  // expects a value
```

Comment: Thank you. I use boost, so I replaces std:: with boost:: in your code. And unfortinetaly I am getting compiler errors : error C2923: 'boost::enable_if' : 'boost::is_enum<T>::value' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'Cond'

Comment: template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_enum<T>::value, std::istream&>::type
operator >>(std::istream &is, T& enumVar)
{
    std::cout << "enum\n";
    int intVal;
    is >> intVal;
    enumVar = static_cast<T>(intVal); // note the explicit cast to make it legal
    return is;
}